# cURL port refuse on window command prompt

Tags: curl

I was following the example tutorial to setup my cURL environment and to test whether it functional with this [link](https://simonlearningsqlserver.wordpress.com/tag/elasticsearch-on-windows/). But unfortunately I obtain an error message right after i execute the command `curl.exe -XPUT localhost:9200/test/type/1 -d {"test":"text"}`

The error message:

```
{"error":
{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse"}],
"type":"mapper_parsing_exception",
"reason":"failed to parse",
"caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected end-of-input within/between OBJECT entries\n 
at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.InputStreamStreamInput@75d8c4a5; line: 1, column: 15]"}},
"status":400}curl: (7) Failed to connect to  port 80: Connection refused
```

I'm sorry I'm new to this approach clearly I don't understand the concept

why does this happen and what is the solution?

Comment: - localhost – this is the host you are posting to this json data.
- In a Windows command prompt you’ll need to escape the double-quote characters with a leading backslash e.g {\“test\”:\”text\”}

Comment: well window and linux environment starting to confusing me, thanks to your effort it solved